# How can i fix the constraints and indexes in neo4j for a changed record?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

I changed the name of a record in neo4j. Now I'm getting an error that hints at a pending migration.

```
class CreateOrganization < Neo4j::Migrations::Base
  def up
    execute("MATCH (n:Institution) SET n:Organization REMOVE n:Institution RETURN n")
  end

  def down
    execute("MATCH (n:Organization) SET n:Institution REMOVE n:Organization RETURN n")
  end
end
```

rails 5.1.4

neo4j 3.3.2

When I check with `CALL db.constraints` I can see that they still point to Institution. The goal is for them to point to Organization.

`"CONSTRAINT ON ( institution:Institution ) ASSERT institution.uuid IS UNIQUE"`

the error looks like this...

```
Neo4j::DeprecatedSchemaDefinitionError in SessionsController#new
Some schema elements were defined by the model (which is no longer 
supported), but they do not exist in the database. Run the following to 
create them if you haven't already: rake 
neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Organization,uuid] rake 
neo4j:generate_schema_migration[index,Organization,sector] And then run 
`rake neo4j:migrate` (zshell users may need to escape the brackets)
```

When I run

`rake neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Organization,uuid]`

I get

`zsh: no matches found: neo4j:generate_schema_migration[constraint,Organization,uuid]`

UPDATE: After I created the migration provided by Brian in his answer, the part of the error related to the constraint was gone. However the part of the error related to the index remained. I tried to use the helpers the add and drop indexes from the models.

```
class AddIndexToOrganization < Neo4j::Migrations::Base
  def up
    add_index :Organization, :uuid
    drop_index :Institution, :uuid
  end

  def down
    drop_index :Organization, :uuid
    add_index :Institution, :uuid
  end
end
```

I then try to run the migration. This throws and error:

```
== 20180224004338 AddIndexToOrganization: running... 
===========================
rake aborted!
Neo4j::MigrationError: Duplicate index for Organization#uuid
```

Interestingly when I use `CALL db.indexes` I can't find an index on Organization and this remains `"INDEX ON :Institution(sector)"  "Institution"`

Answer (score 1):

Running `MATCH (n:Institution) SET n:Organization REMOVE n:Institution RETURN n` doesn't change the constraint, just the label.  The constraint will still be there setup for the old label.  You should be able to use the `drop_constraint` and `add_constraint` helpers in a new migration (see the [docs page](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/9.1.x/Migrations.html#migration-helpers) for the migration helpers).  It should look something like:

```
class CreateOrganization < Neo4j::Migrations::Base
  def up
    add_constraint(:Organization, :uuid)
    remove_constraint(:Institution, :uuid)
  end

  def down
    remove_constraint(:Organization, :uuid)
    add_constraint(:Institution, :uuid)
  end
end
```

Comment: And something same for indexes?

Comment: Adding or removing constraints automatically adds / removes the associated indexes.  You can add / remove an index without a constraint, but you can't add / remove a constraint without an index